# ASP.NET Core Authentication for Server side Blazor app

Tags: blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-blazor

I am currently learning ASP.NET Core. As a first step I want to port an older project from ASP.NET WebForms to ASP.NET Core Blazor. Unfortunately, I have some difficulties with setting up a authentification.

As far as I've read, there are many ways to do an authentification.
Cookie Based
Identity Based
etc.

But I am not sure which one I should use. Also what is the key point of an Identity based authentication?

I want to compare username and password with an existing Firebird database. If the enetered crendetials matches an entry in the database, the user should be logged in. The authentification should be required for the entire app, except the login page. The authentication should last for around 8 hours.

Which authetication method should I use? And how can I use my own checking method to verify an user? I don't want to use the build in database from the app that comes with this AppDbContext stuff.

Thanks!
-Marvin

Comment: Hi.you can use token authentication,there is a Expires property that you can set it to 8 hours,also you can use your own tables to create a login method,if successful will return the token that you save it in browser local storage,then use it(in header) for other requests

Comment: @mrapi thanks for your comment! Do you know any good documentation for token based authentication? - Marvin

Comment: maybe this: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api     also  https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/